# Cygnus installation

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I try to install cygnus. I install yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel and run , my problem is:

```
Then, the developed classes must be packaged in a Java jar file which must be added to the APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib directory:

 $ git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors.git
 $ git checkout release/0.1
 $ cd fiware-connectors/flume
 $ APACHE_MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn package
 $ cp target/cosmos-injector-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib
```

in this step, I create cygnus.jar not cosmos-injector-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar , and  # APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/cosmos-injector.conf not exist on my flume directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alejandro, I recommend you to install last version of Cygnus (currenty, [0.7.1](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/releases/tag/release-0.7.1)), which can be installed through RPM packages (recommended). Simply configure the FIWARE repo and install it using yum (CentOS):

```
$ sudo cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/fiware.repo <<EOL [Fiware]
name=FIWARE
repository baseurl=http://repositories.testbed.fi-ware.eu/repo/rpm/x86_64/ 
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOL
$ yum install cygnus
```

You can find the Cygnus Quick Start Guide at [this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/blob/master/flume/doc/quick_start_guide.md) link.

The [README](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/blob/0.7.1/flume/README.md) will give you extended information about the tool.

Advanced topics can be found at the [doc/](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/0.7.1/flume/doc) folder.